# Can't Load ImageView from MediaStore Camera Android

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, android-glide, android-external-storage

I have an ImageView inside an alertdialog,I would like to show the picture that was taken by the camera in the ImageView with the height and width that I gave to to it and **Not** as a thumbnail.

I don't get an error inside the logcat just see a blank square for my ImageView where there was a default Image and not the picture that was taken by the camera in this imageview.

Further more I am able to load images from gallery.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code.

**XML**

```
   <ImageView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_to_set"
        android:src="@drawable/picture"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ImageView>
```

**Files Dir**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>

</paths>
```

**Manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.musicplayer.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/files_dir"/>
        </provider>
```

**Main Activity**

```
cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"pic.jpg");
                        imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this
                                , "com.example.musicplayer.provider", file);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                });
```

**I tried several ways to load the picture was taken by the camera into the image view
Glide/picasso**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            ImageView imageViewToSet=v.findViewById(R.id.image_to_set);
            Picasso.get().load(file.getAbsolutePath()).fit().centerCrop().into(imageViewToSet);
            v.requestLayout();
            v.invalidate();
        }
```

Comment: Before you do the load() use file.exists().

Comment: Your code wil not work on Android Q.